# how am I able to write different languages inside a table in LaTex file?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, luatex, languages, polyglossia

I am using a `CEUR-WS.org` proceedings style. But I am not able to write different languages inside a table, where the different languages are visible outside the table.

```
\documentclass[
]{ceurart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{hindi,bengali}

\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Noto Serif Bengali}

\title{Try}
\author{Name Surname}
\date{September 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Table Caption}
    \label{tab:tweet} 
    \centering
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{ l | p{27em} | l }
        \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
        \noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
        1 & \begin{hindi} मूर्ख लड़की \end{hindi}  &  \\
        2 & \begin{bengali} পরীক \end{bengali}&\\ 
        \noalign{\smallskip}\hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}

Here's some Hindi: \begin{hindi} हिन्दवी आनलाइन हिंदी शब्दकोश का प्रयोग करें। टाइप करके उसका अर्थ ढूँढ भी सकते हैं. हिन्दी-अंग्रेजी शब्दकोश \end{hindi}

\begin{bengali}
পরীক
\end{bengali}

\end{document}
```

but it is showing like that.
[image: The output of the latewx file]

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. 1) `CEUR-WR.cls` file renews the definition of `table` environment. It adds `\sffamily` to the table content. I am not sure, but it looks like it is the culprit. If you remove the `table` environment; comment out `\caption` and `\label`; you get the desired output. So the problem is with the new `table` definition.

Comment: 2) Looking at the attached screenshot I assume that you are using LuaLaTeX. You need to add `Renderer=Harfbuzz` as a parameter to both the `\newfontfamily` commands in order to get the rendering correctly. e.g. `\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Noto Serif Devanagari}`

Comment: I have commented out `\sffamily`. now it's working perfectly. Thank You.

Comment: Glad that it works now! :)